# I am declaring private variable and function by creating a stateless class, but when I used function in body the function is showing error

Tags: flutter, function

[I am declaring private variable and function by creating a stateless class, but when I used function in body the function is showing error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVN0.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVN0.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVN0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Function to VoidCallback..It will work

```
final VoidCallback _handler;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).